# Does jdbc dataset store all rows in jvm memory

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jdbc

I am using a java jdbc application to fetch about 500,000 records from DB. The Database being used is Oracle. I write the data into a file as soon as each row is fetched. Since it takes about an hour to complete fetching the entire data, I am trying to increase the fetch size of the result set. I have seen in multiple links that while increasing the fetch size one should be careful about the memory consumption. Does increasing the fetch size actually increase the heap memory used by the jvm?
Suppose if the fetch size is 10 and the program query returns 100 rows in total. During the first fetch the resultset contains 10 record. Once I read the first 10 records the resultset fetches the next 10. Does this mean that after the 2nd fetch the dataset will contain 20 records? Are the earlier 10 records still maintained in memory or are they removed while fetching the newer batch?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Oracle driver will only hold the number of rows defined by the fetchSize in memory. So the rows from the first fetch will be freed and garbage collected when the second fetch is done. But an hour for 500.000 rows seems awfully slow. Are you sure that you are limited by the fetching, not by the statement itself? Does the statement run for an hour if you use `set autotrace traceonly` in SQL*Plus? You should measure the time between `executeQuery()` and the first `ResultSet.next()` call - my guess is, that you are waiting for Oracle to prepare your query results

Comment: Yes, an hour is including the fetch for all the query results. I hope increasing the fetch size reduces the overall fetch time.

Comment: The result statement which i execute fetches data from external db from the internet, and i start writing into my local file from the resultset, it starts writing but whenever the internet gets disconnected the writing get interrupted. Is it because the resultset fetches data and writes into file dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  Different drivers may behave differently and different [`ResultSet` settings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) may behave differently.

If you have a `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`, `FETCH_FORWARD`, `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` `ResultSet`, the driver will almost certainly actively store in memory the number of rows that corresponds to your fetch size (of course data for earlier rows will remain in memory for some period of time until it is garbage collected).  If you have a `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` `ResultSet`, on the other hand, it is very likely that the driver would store all the data that was fetched in memory in order to allow you to scroll backwards and forwards through the data.  That's not the only possible way to implement this behavior, so different drivers (and different versions of drivers) may have different behaviors but it is the simplest and the way that most drivers I've come across behave.

Answer (score 1):

While increasing the fetch size may help the performance a bit I would also look into tuning the SDU size which controls the size of the packets at the sqlnet layer. Increasing the SDU size can speed up data transfers.

Of course the time it takes to fetch these 500,000 rows largely depends on how much data you're fetching. If it takes an hour I'm guessing you're fetching a lot of data and/or you're doing it from a remote client over a WAN.

**To change the SDU size:**

First change the default SDU size on the server to 32k (starting in 11.2.0.3 you can even use 64kB and up to 2MB starting in 12c) by changing or adding this line in sqlnet.ora on the server:
DEFAULT_SDU_SIZE=32767

Then modify your JDBC URL:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(SDU=32767)(HOST=...)(PORT=...))(CONNECT_DATA=